# Restoring MySQL database from .frm and .ibd files

Tags: mysql, wordpress, database-backups, database-restore

I need to restore a MySQL database using .frm and .ibd files these, as well as a db.opt file is what I have in the folder.

Please, in layman's terms can someone explain to me how I can restore this database?

This database is from a crashed laragon WordPress site that is no longer connecting to the database. I would like to restore the MySQL file and then import it to the WordPress installation.

I tried this but it just keeps giving errors and doesn't work out for me: https://mgfn.net/how-to-restore-wordpress-database-from-frm-ibd-files-step-by-step/

**EDIT:** I had laragon running with MySQL and Apache running when my laptop died while on battery.

MySQL on laragon would not start when my laptop was back up and running. It had crashed. I looked for solutions online but nothing that I had tried has worked including adding and switching to a more recent version of MySQL to laragon.

In the hopes that sometime I will find a solution online for me that gets the MySQL back up and running, I would leave laragon as it is and install XAMPP to see if I could restore the database by restoring/compiling those files into one MySQL file and importing that MySQL file into a new WordPress installation.

I do not know my way around MySQL, so I am asking for help in layman's terms, please.

So I am wanting to move a database from laragon to XAMPP using a folder of .frm and .ibd files.

I have not tried reinstalling laragon and simply copying and pasting the database folder yet as I saw someone mention it online saying that it did not work for them and they had to compile everything into one MySQL file and then import it via phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Does this help https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16875/restore-table-from-frm-and-ibd-file

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the *exact same version* of your Laragon package, then shutting down its MySQL, then replacing its database files with your rescued files. That might work. But, with respect, sometime soon it may make sense to simply build up a new development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Restoring from those database container files -- .frm and friends -- is a sketchy procedure that only works as a last resort, and then only maybe. Your question didn't say why you have to do it that way.

Your best bet, if the MySQL server still runs, is to connect to it from a MySQL client and dump the data to a .SQL file. That will be easiest to restore to another server.  Look at your dead site's `wp-config.php` file and get the values shown here.

```php
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', "example-database-name");

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', "example-username");

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', "example-password");

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', "host.example.com");
```

Then use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) to get the SQL file. Like this, from a command line.

```bash
mysqldump -h host.example.com -u example-username -p example-database-name >saved.sql
```

Substitute your actual values for the examples, obvs.

(Or you can use phpmyadmin to do this database dump, if you have access to it.)

You can then load that `saved.sql` file into another server quite easily.

As far as troubleshooting your approach to doing this, you haven't given us enough information to help you. The format of those .frm and other files can change from version to version of MySQL.

Comment: I have edited my question with what has brought me to this dilemma. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  Thanks for clarifying your question.